# problem on delete views (ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view)

Tags: oracle, plsql

i am using oracle 19c.
i run a delete with function in another schema and i get error

```
create user USER1  identified by USER1;
create user USER2  identified by USER2;
create user USER3  identified by USER3;
grant connect to USER1;
grant connect to USER2;
grant connect to USER3;
grant unlimited tablespace to USER1;
grant unlimited tablespace to USER2;
grant unlimited tablespace to USER3;

grant create procedure to USER1;
grant create table to USER1;
grant create view to USER2;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE USER1.PKG1 IS
  FUNCTION FUNC1(p_DTE DATE) RETURN VARCHAR2;
END PKG1;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY USER1.PKG1 IS
  FUNCTION FUNC1(p_DTE DATE) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  BEGIN
      RETURN NULL;
  END;
END PKG1;
/
GRANT ALL     ON USER1.PKG1 TO USER2 WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT EXECUTE ON USER1.PKG1 TO USER3;
create table USER1.TAB1(  str1 varchar2(100),  num1 number,  dte1 DATE)
/
insert into USER1.TAB1 (STR1, NUM1, DTE1)values ('S1', 1, SYSDATE);
insert into USER1.TAB1 (STR1, NUM1, DTE1)values ('S2', 2, SYSDATE-1);
COMMIT;
/
GRANT ALL ON USER1.TAB1 TO USER2 WITH GRANT OPTION;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW USER2.VIW1 AS SELECT * FROM USER1.TAB1
/
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON USER2.VIW1 TO USER3;
```

after create environment

LOGIN WITH USER3
BELOW CODE HAS ERROR: ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view

```
DELETE USER2.VIW1 WHERE USER1.PKG1.FUNC1(DTE1)='0';
```

LOGIN WITH USER2
BELOW CODE RUN SUCCESSFULLY.

```
DELETE USER2.VIW1 WHERE USER1.PKG1.FUNC1(DTE1)='0';
```

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8005.htm#SQLRF01505):
*For you to delete rows from the base table of a view, the owner of the schema containing the view must have the DELETE object privilege on the base table. Also, if the view is in a schema other than your own, then you must have the DELETE object privilege on the view.*
Not sure, but could it be that USER3 has no privileges on table USER1.TAB1 !?
In your code there is

```sql
GRANT ALL ON USER1.TAB1 TO USER2 WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

... regarding base table USER1.TAB1 there is nothing granted TO USER3 - but just to the view. Did you try to add

```sql
GRANT ALL ON USER1.TAB1 TO USER3 WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

If that doesn't help then it could be because the use of function as mentioned [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01732_data_manipulation_operation.htm).
The where condition is set **on virtual columns derived from functions or expressions**, then the view may only be queried.